# Is it possible to use MUI DatePicker without a 3rd party library for the dates?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The documentation on the website seems to suggest that you need a 3rd party library like Dayjs, Moment, etc. However I am trying to limit the number of installs on my application.

I have been trying to use the DatePicker without one, but am receiving this error. [Photo of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN4mh.png)

Comment: yes and no,  yes - you could write your own DateAdapter and pass it down to the LocalizationProvider or you will have to use one of the supported DateAdapters. https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/getting-started/#code-setup

Comment: Please include the full error in your question. Don't post screenshots of code or errors